Python multithreaded mode using undetected chromedriver
[ENG]
Hello! I recently started learning how to work with browsers in python and ran into a problem.
I can't create multithreading of browser sessions using undetected chromedriver. In my code, sessions are started one after the other, but they must be started at the same time. I tried to do this using GPT chat, but it didn't help at all:(
Here is the source code, with basic functionality.Thank you in advance!
[RUS]
Здравствуйте! Совсем недавно начал изучать работу с браузерами в пайтон и столкнулся с проблемой.
Не могу создать многопоточность сессий браузеров, используя undetected chromedriver. В моём коде сессии запускаются друг за другом, но должны запускаться одновременно. Пытался сделать это с помощью чата GPT, но он совсем не помог :(
Соурс код, с базовым функционалом. Находится ниже! Заранее благодарю!
import time
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from rich import print

while True:
    print("\n[green]❤️[white]   How much sessions :")
    session_count = int(input("==>  Enter the response in the console :  "))

    print("\n[green]❤️[white]    Select the site you want to [green]visit [white]: [green] example / example_1 / example_2")
    platform = input("==>  Enter the response in the console :  ")

    if platform in ["example", "example_1", "example_2"]:
        break
    else:
        print("\n❗️ [white]ENTER [red]example[white] or [red]example_1[white] or [red]example_2")

# If ok
print(f"[green]==>  [white]The site is selected: [green]{platform}")

# Start session
number_of_session = 0
for i in range(session_count):
    # Launching the browser
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=518,600")
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options)
    if platform == "example":
        driver.get('https://example.com/')
    elif platform == "example_1":
        driver.get('https://example.com/')
    elif platform == "example_2":
        driver.get('https://example.com/')

    print("Session numer ", number_of_session + 1, "has launched")
    number_of_session += 1
# We display a completion message
print("All sessions are running")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)

GPT chat created an error code:

It is not possible to create a file because it already exists :
C:\Users\Me\appdata\roaming\undetected_chromedriver\undetected\chromedriver-win32\chromedriver.exe
Session number 2 has launched
Exception in thread Thread-1 (run_session):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1073, in _bootstrap_inner
self.run()
File "C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\threading.py", line 1010, in run
self._target(*self._args, **self.kwargs)
File "c:\Users\ALEX\Desktop\SENDER\ASK.py", line 10, in run_session
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
File "C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver_init.py", line 258, in init
self.patcher.auto()
File "C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 178, in auto
self.unzip_package(self.fetch_package())
File "C:\Users\ALEX\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python312\Lib\site-packages\undetected_chromedriver\patcher.py", line 310, in unzip_package
os.rename(os.path.join(self.zip_path, exe_path), self.executable_path)

Source code by GPT:
import time
import threading
import undetected_chromedriver as uc
from rich import print

def run_session(platform, session_number):
    # Launching the browser
    options = uc.ChromeOptions()
    options.add_argument("--window-size=518,600")
    driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=True)

    if platform == "example":
        driver.get('https://example.com/')
    elif platform == "example_1":
        driver.get('https://example.com/')
    elif platform == "example_2":
        driver.get('https://example.com/')

    print(f"Session number {session_number + 1} has launched")

# Main program
while True:
    print("\n[green]❤️[white]   How much sessions :")
    session_count = int(input("==>  Enter the response in the console :  "))

    print("\n[green]❤️[white]    Select the site you want to [green]visit [white]: [green] example / example_1 / example_2")
    platform = input("==>  Enter the response in the console :  ")

    if platform in ["example", "example_1", "example_2"]:
        break
    else:
        print("\n❗️ [white]ENTER [red]example[white] or [red]example_1[white] or [red]example_2")

# If ok
print(f"[green]==>  [white]The site is selected: [green]{platform}")

# Start sessions in parallel
threads = []
for i in range(session_count):
    thread = threading.Thread(target=run_session, args=(platform, i))
    threads.append(thread)
    thread.start()

# Wait for all sessions to complete
for thread in threads:
    thread.join()

# We display a completion message
print("All sessions are running")

while True:
    time.sleep(1)




Just change use_subprocess to False or default
driver = uc.Chrome(options=options, use_subprocess=False)

This will fix you error and make it multithreading

Its not help...
